# Не могу понять простейший алгоритм

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Нужно посчитать XOR-ы всех чисел на заданном отрезке. Операция xor мне знакома, но я не знаю как посчитать xor-ы всех чисел. Пытался XOR-ить сначало первое число с всеми остальными и эти XOR-ы XOR-ил между собой, так же до последнего числа и потом ещё эти резульаты XOR-ил, но это неправильно.

Comment: `a1 ^ a2 ^ a3 ^ a4...`

Comment: *Нужно посчитать XOR-ы всех чисел на заданном отрезке.* Чем ксорить влоб (чисел - дохрена), надо просто подумать, каким получится N-й бит. Намекну - он совершенно однозначно вычисляется из значений границ несложной арифметической формулой.

Answer (score 5):

По понятным причинам, `xor` между четным числом и следующим за ним нечетным равно `1`. Поэтому, а также потому, что `xor` - ассоциативна.

```
0 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ ... ^ 2n-2 ^ 2n-1 =
(0 ^ 1) ^ (2 ^ 3) ^ ... ^ (2n-2 ^ 2n-1) =
1 ^ 1 ^ ... ^ 1 ^ 1 (n раз)
```

Т.е. если последовательность начинается с четного числа и заканчивается нечетным, то результат для нее будет равен `1` если общее количество членов не делится на `4`, и `0` если делится.

Т.е, например

```
40 ^ 41 ^ ... ^ 99999998 ^ 99999999 = 0
```

т.к `40` - четное, `99999999` - нечетное и `99999999 - 40 + 1` делится на 4

Если же последовательность начинается с нечетного и/или заканчивается на четное, эти числа можно "доксорить" к результату, потому, `xor` еще и коммутативна.

```
39 ^ 40 ^ 41 ^ ... ^ 99999998 ^ 99999999 ^ 100000000 = 
(40 ^ 41 ^ ... ^ 99999998 ^ 99999999) ^ 39 ^ 100000000 =
0 ^ 39 ^ 100000000
```

Ну и возможно поможет тот факт, что операция `xor` обращает саму себя

```
a ^ b ^ a = b
```

Поэтому

```
(0 ^ 1 ^ ... ^ n) ^ (0 ^ 1 ^ ... ^ m) = n+1 ^ n+2 ^ ... ^ m
```

где n ≤ m, но это уже на ваше усмотрение

Answer (score 4):

Что-то типа

```
unsigned int res = 0;
for(unsigned int i = left; i <= right; ++i)
    res ^= i;
```

Comment: как можно ускорить данный алгоритм ? лимит до 1 секунды, а он больше 2 делает. left от 1, а right до 10 на 18 степени

Comment: @Vorgw3 `лимит до 1 секунды` - на какую задачу?

Comment: Как спросили - так я и ответил. Хотите более точный ответ - давайте более точно условие. Пока нет **абсолютно** точного ТЗ, ответ может быть один - ХЗ. Для такого большого диапазона надо считать иначе, смотреть на каждый бит отдельно. Например, младший бит равен 1, если количество чисел нечетно, и 0, если четно. Дайте URL задачи с проверялкой - будем посмотреть...